# how do i club values from my right table when doing a Left join

Tags: sqlite, left-join

i have 2 tables total

[image]

and ordered

[image]

I am looking to join the 2 tables and give me the difference left, however when i do a left join, my first table shows the correct value and the second table only gives me the total result of the 1st available value

```
SELECT        
sum(total.order_value) total,
sum(ordered.order_value) ordered,
sum(total.order_value - ordered.AOV_value) as left to order  
from total
left join ordered on total.order_value = ordered.order_value
    """
```

The result i get is

[image]

instead of the 470 i should see 760. Its picking up the 1st available value from the right table instead of totaling them. my version of sqlite3 does not support full outer and right join so dont know what else i can do.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: That query does not give that result on that data, once corrected for `as left to order` syntax error and `ordered.AOV_value` no such column error. It gives 860 in the "ordered" column (because each 50 is joined twice).

Comment: how are you doing the as left to order? is that instead of the left join?

Comment: copy/pasted the sql as posted here. removed the problem line  (`sum(total.order_value - ordered.AOV_value) as left to order  `). used sample data as posted here. using db browser for sqlite.